# AsyncTask: onPostExecute() doesn't get invoked

Tags: android, api, android-asynctask

I've tried everything, but nothings works.

I'm trying to call an Api, which works. However, onPostExecute() doesn't get called which makes that my callback doesn't work.

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
class RetrieveInput extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
            String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
            return result;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d("Error", "Error fetching data");
            Log.d("STACKTRACE", ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        repo.setString(result);
    }
}
```

This is where the AsyncTask gets called:

```
public void getString() {
    if (url != null) {
        RetrieveInput input = new RetrieveInput();
        input.execute(url);
    }
}
```

This is where my callback is located:

```
public class UserRepository implements IRepository {

    private Connection connection;
    private String result;
    private Gson gson;

    public UserRepository() {
        this.connection = new Connection(this);
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

    public User find(String userName) {
        connection.setUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/api-0.1.0/users/get/" + userName);
        connection.getString();
        User user = gson.fromJson(this.result, User.class);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void setString(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does doInBackground() get called or even that is not?

Comment: It gets called! The result string contains the JSON

Comment: Maybe the server is taking too long to respond. Try using `connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);` to make sure the function always returns. Also try debugging your app by placing breakpoints at different lines of your `doInBackground` method.

Comment: try logging `String result` in onPostExecute, just to make sure it is not called. Also, try debugging with appropriate break points.

Comment: I've debugged with breakpoints. The server responds, the string result gets filled with JSON. Set a breakpoint in onPostExecute(), doesn't get called.

Comment: Also second parameter should be void

Comment: Tried Void as well, doesn't make the diff. But I'll change it.

Comment: As Anonymous said `AsyncTask<String, String, String>`, the second parameter is for `onProgressUpdate`, should be `Void`, or else set it to `Integer` and implement also this method.

Comment: instead of catching `IOException e`, try catching `Exception e` just in case there is some other exception

Comment: Already tried that. No exceptions...

Comment: debug your code and check where the flow is going after doinbackground().

Comment: To my Activity. onPostExecute() never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

From the official android developers site:

> There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class
>   to work properly:
>
> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
> - execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
> - Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
>     The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

I would emphasize on the 3rd bullet. `execute` must be invoked on the **UI** thread. In your code it shows that `execute` is called from a `getString()` method but it is not clear if this method exists in a class belonging to the UI thread e.g. an activity. I suppose there is no UI thread in which the `onPostExecute` method can be executed.

Comment: Hello, this method belongs to a class called Connection. It's not an activity, but it gets created in a repository and that repository gets created in an activity. So I should be on the UI thread right?

Comment: Yeap, you have to create and call it in your activity! See bullets 2 and 3

Comment: I extended my connection class (with the getString method) with the Activity class. Still makes no diff, or am I missing something?

Comment: @AswinPAshok I dont know, I suppose it is not correct since it will try to force to run also the `doInBackground` method on the UI which is wrong. But I am not sure, haven't tested it.

Comment: @KevinStrijbos Why extend the Connection class and not use your main activity for this? Just extending your class to activity won't solve your problem, since this activity is not registered to the android application lifecycle properly. Try yo keep your code clean and separated, including the `AsyncTask` in the `Connection` class your are messing your backend with the UI. The optimal would be `Connection` and `UserRepository` to be completely agnostic/decoupled of UI and `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have another exception in `doInBackground()` Method add this catch block to your try catch :

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.getStackTrace()
}
```

and also check your log and make sure your log line is not printed in logcat
so you will have this:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(params[0]);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    return result;
}catch (IOException ex) {
   Log.d("Error", "Error fetching data");
   Log.d("STACKTRACE", ex.getStackTrace().toString());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.getStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no exceptions getting thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an exception in your network call that is returned and hence null is sent as the result.Also you are returning result in try and again sending null as result at the end of the method which gets overridden.So alter your code like this

```
 String dataResult = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
        String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        dataResult = result;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("Error", "Error fetching data");
        Log.d("STACKTRACE", ex.getStackTrace().toString());
    } finally {
        return dataResult;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help unfortunately!

Comment: oh i guessed you were overriding the result from the server